# Redirect to route not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a problem redirecting to a route which may be a result of a lack of understanding about how it's supposed to work.

Here is my routeProvider:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/Content/templates/landingPage.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
        ...
```

A user in my app can log in at any time and when they do I want to redirect them to my home route.  Eg:

```
function loginSuccessful() {
    $location.path('/');
}
```

I'm trying to test this on a registration confirmation page I have which is on the following URL:

```
http://localhost:55841/account/register?token=da924359-130a-4a5c-9b8e-4f44267b4d6e#/
```

When `loginSuccessful()` is called, rather than redirect, it simply appends `#/` to the URL.  I'm expecting it to redirect to the app root (`http://localhost:55841/`).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: angular routing working correctly in your case...$location.path will only the part after the `#` it doesn;t care about the before part

Comment: @pankajparkar: OK. So is there a solution other than `window.location('/')`?  Ideally the page wouldn't refresh.

Comment: no it will refresh the whole page..in first place why you are running your SPA..in such url & expecting to change url appears before hash..that is not a pure way to load SPA...that will cause page to hit server .. and your application will get loaded again

Comment: Have you tried enabling [html5mode](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)?